# word_tokenizer in dplyr pipe function - output to list

Tags: r

I am trying to use the dplyr pipe functions and apply `word_tokenizer` from the `text2vec` package.

Some data:

```
text <- c("Because I could not stop for Death I add additional text-",
          "He kindly stopped for me some additional text to act as a filler -",
          "The Carriage held but just Ourselves more additional text to add to the body of the text-",
          "and Immortality plus some more words to fill the text a little")

ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
output <- c(1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, text, output))
df$text <- as.character(df$text)



library(text2vec)

df %>%
  word_tokenizer(text)
```

Gives a warning, whilst;

```
df %>%
  mutate(word_tokenizer(text))
```

Gives some output but not the list format I expect.

The correct method is to use `word_tokenizer(df$text)`. I am just wondering how to do this using the pipe functions since I have some other processing before this part.

I would also like to complete the pipe using `itoken()` and `create_vocabulary()`.

Comment: `df %>%  mutate(new_col = word_tokenizer(text))` does give you output same as `word_tokenizer(df$text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `with`. The key is to understand how the pipe works and how `word_tokenizer` works.

The pipe takes the output of whatever's on its Left Hand Side, and passes that as the first argument (by default, but can be any argument) to the function on its Right Hand Side (RHS). `word_tokenizer` expects a string as argument.

You have a dataframe on the LHS of the pipe, so on the RHS you need a function that accepts a dataframe as an argument and can pass a column in that dataframe to to another function. In this case passing the string in the `text` field to `word_tokenizer`. `with` can do just that.

```
text <- c("Because I could not stop for Death I add additional text-",
          "He kindly stopped for me some additional text to act as a filler -",
          "The Carriage held but just Ourselves more additional text to add to the body of the text-",
          "and Immortality plus some more words to fill the text a little")

ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
output <- c(1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, text, output))
df$text <- as.character(df$text)

library(text2vec)

df %>%
  with(word_tokenizer(text))

# [[1]]
# [1] "Because"    "I"          "could"      "not"        "stop"      
# [6] "for"        "Death"      "I"          "add"        "additional"
# [11] "text"      
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "He"         "kindly"     "stopped"    "for"        "me"        
# [6] "some"       "additional" "text"       "to"         "act"       
# [11] "as"         "a"          "filler"    
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "The"        "Carriage"   "held"       "but"        "just"      
# [6] "Ourselves"  "more"       "additional" "text"       "to"        
# [11] "add"        "to"         "the"        "body"       "of"        
# [16] "the"        "text"      
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "and"         "Immortality" "plus"        "some"       
# [5] "more"        "words"       "to"          "fill"       
# [9] "the"         "text"        "a"           "little"
```

You also asked how to pipe the output of `text2vec` to `itoken` and the output of that to `create_vocabulary`. Again the key is to understand what the function LHS returns and what the function on the RHS expects. `text2vec` returns a list and `itoken` expects an iterable object; lists are iterable so just pipe the output of `text2vec` straight to `itoken`. In you comment you're trying to use `with` again as though the output of `text2vec` were a dataframe. The way I figured this out was by looking at the help pages for the functions you're using; that showed me what types of arguments they were expecting. If you don't know what type a function returns, you can either consult the help pages or pipe its output into `class`.

```
library(text2vec)

df %>%
  with(word_tokenizer(text)) %>%
  itoken() %>%
  create_vocabulary()

# |===============================================================| 100%
# Number of docs: 4 
# 0 stopwords:  ... 
# ngram_min = 1; ngram_max = 1 
# Vocabulary: 
#   term term_count doc_count
# 1:     Because          1         1
# 2:        stop          1         1
# 3:        just          1         1
# 4:         not          1         1
# 5: Immortality          1         1
# 6:      little          1         1
# 7:      filler          1         1
# 8:      kindly          1         1
# 9:          of          1         1
# 10:         and          1         1
# 11:        plus          1         1
# 12:        fill          1         1
# 13:       could          1         1
# 14:          me          1         1
# 15:    Carriage          1         1
# 16:         but          1         1
# 17:        body          1         1
# 18:     stopped          1         1
# 19:          as          1         1
# 20:          He          1         1
# 21:         act          1         1
# 22:         The          1         1
# 23:       Death          1         1
# 24:       words          1         1
# 25:        held          1         1
# 26:   Ourselves          1         1
# 27:        some          2         2
# 28:        more          2         2
# 29:           I          2         1
# 30:           a          2         2
# 31:         add          2         2
# 32:         for          2         2
# 33:         the          3         2
# 34:  additional          3         3
# 35:          to          4         3
# 36:        text          5         4
# term term_count doc_count
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I am trying to take it further using `with(word_tokenizer(text)) %>%
  with(itoken(.)) %>%
  with(create_vocabulary())` but I get "cannot find function create_vocabulary()

Comment: @user8959427 I've updated my answer to complete the pipeline you requested through `create_vocabulary`. Would you edit your question to ask about that there instead of in the comments?

Comment: Thanks! will do now